# array_agg DISTINCT and ORDER

Tags: postgresql, left-join, sql-order-by, distinct

I'm trying to make a query in PostgreSQL for include results from 2 (or more) tables using left join lateral, and I need to have one record for each record for table entidad_a_ (main table) and all the records from table entidad_b_ must be included in one field generated by array_agg. And in this array, I have to delete duplicate elements and I have to preserve order array in main table.
I need to execute this SQL query:

```
SELECT entidad_a_._id_ AS "_id", CASE WHEN count(entidadB) > 0 THEN array_agg(DISTINCT entidadB._id,ordinality order by ordinality)
ELSE NULL END AS "entidadB"
FROM entidad_a_ as entidad_a_, unnest(entidad_a_.entidad_b_) WITH ORDINALITY AS u(entidadb_id, ordinality)
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
SELECT entidad_b_3._id_ AS "_id", entidad_b_3.label_ AS "label"
FROM entidad_b_ as entidad_b_3
WHERE entidad_b_3._id_ = entidadb_id
GROUP BY entidad_b_3._id_
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
) entidadB ON TRUE
GROUP BY entidad_a_._id_
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
```

But I have errors....
How can I have these results?

**Edited:**
My error is:
ERROR: function array_agg (integer, bigint) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 69

If the query is:
......array_agg (DISTINCT entidadB._id order by ordinality).....
The eror is:
ERROR: in an aggregate with DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in argument list
SQL state: 42P10
Character: 110

My problem is the combination of array_agg, DISTINCT, and ORDER by

Comment: And what is the error? Please **[edit]** your question and add the error message you get - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: What don't you understand about the error messages? What did you learn googling them (without your specific names) and googling your title? Why didn't casting work? Why are you not using distinct & order together with an argument?

Comment: Could you explain and example of using distinct & order together? I'm obtaing errors using it in combination with array_agg. Now I'm trying to create a custom aggregate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!! I've created a postgres extension with a custom aggregation.

```
    CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_dist (anyelement)
(
    sfunc = array_agg_transfn_dist,
    stype = internal,
    finalfunc = array_agg_finalfn_dist,
    finalfunc_extra
);
```

Creating functions and c code for this custom functions.